# Terminal doesn't show input after running threading nmap scan

Tags: python, terminal, python-multithreading, nmap

i have written a NMap-TCP-Port-Scanner in python and everything works just fine except that i'm no longer able to see what i'm writing on the terminal.

First things first.

The code:

```
import argparse, nmap, sys
from threading import *

def initParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("tgtHost", help="Specify target host")
    parser.add_argument("tgtPort", help="Specify target port")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return (args.tgtHost,args.tgtPort.split(","))

def nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    lock = Semaphore(value=1)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        t = Thread(target=nmapScanThread, args=(tgtHost, tgtPort, lock, nm))
        t.start()

def nmapScanThread(tgtHost, tgtPort, lock, nm):
    nm.scan(tgtHost, tgtPort)
    state = nm[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
    lock.acquire()
    print("Port {} is {}".format(tgtPort, state))
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (tgtHost, tgtPorts) = initParser()
    nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
    sys.exit(0)
```

So, after i have run the script i don't see what i'm typing on the console anymore, but i can still execute my invisible commands. As you can see i want to start a thread for each port just because i am learning about threading right now.

My assumption is that not all threads are terminated properly because everthing works just fine after i have added "t.join()" to the code.
Unfortunately i couldn't manage to find anything about this issue.

Just like this:

```
import argparse, nmap, sys
from threading import *

def initParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("tgtHost", help="Specify target host")
    parser.add_argument("tgtPort", help="Specify target port")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return (args.tgtHost,args.tgtPort.split(","))

def nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    lock = Semaphore(value=1)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        t = Thread(target=nmapScanThread, args=(tgtHost, tgtPort, lock,  nm))
        t.start()
        t.join()


def nmapScanThread(tgtHost, tgtPort, lock, nm):
    nm.scan(tgtHost, tgtPort)
    state = nm[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
    lock.acquire()
    print("Port {} is {}".format(tgtPort, state))
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (tgtHost, tgtPorts) = initParser()
    nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Is it the proper way to handle this problem or did i mess things up a bit?

Additionally:

I cannot see the join() method as useful in this example because i don't think that there is any major difference to the same script without threading

Comment: In case it's Nmap causing the problem, add `--noninteractive` to your Nmap options to tell it not to look for terminal input.

Comment: Thank ya. That solved the issue.